# Merge MySQL tables into one table

Tags: mysql, database, merge, copy

I have three MySQL tables, each have only one column.

First Table -> Item_No has column item_no

Second Table -> Item_Name has column item_name

Third Table -> Item_Price has column item_price

These three tables contain data related to each others.

I want to merge these three tables into one table containing three columns.

I have created a new table -> Item has three columns item_no, item_name, item_price.

I want to move all the data in the first three tables to the new table(Item).

[image]

Comment: How are your tables related if they all have only one column?

Comment: By which method you can prove which row from second table belong to row in first or third table?

Comment: I mean that the first row in item_no table is related to the first row in item_name and the first row in item_price.

Comment: Can you even guarantee that they are not deleted in past?

Comment: Whoever created this database structure deserves to step on a lego.

Comment: Is there a way to do that?

Comment: This image describe what i want.https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3CUJSn9f4j1NGFWMVpuWC1DeXM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: How did you get the data for the first three tables to start with?

Comment: This was a dbf database, I am trying to convert it to MySQL. and this is the last step.

Comment: Tables in a relational database don't have any inherent ordering, there's no way to relate these tables just by their row numbers.

Comment: Are the three columns in the same table in the DBF file? Why export them seperately? Why not export to CSV and import to Mysql?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same table in the DBF file, I did, I export them to .xls then import them from MySQL, but the problem is i can only import one column a time. when i import item_no, then i want to import item_name, it appends item_name to the table, here are the explanation of what happened https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3CUJSn9f4j1R2JBOG5xMUF3OGc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

With your structure, every `SELECT` statement over same table, can give different result, especially without primary keys (though even primary keys are not guarantee for ordered result).

What you can do is to every row give some ordinal, hoping that in all three tables ordinals will respect initial order, and by those try to join tables.

Answer (score 0):

I don't guarantee that this will work, but it might solve your problem.

```
SET @rank1 := 0;
SET @rank2 := 0;
SET @rank3 := 0;

INSERT INTO new_table (item_no, item_name, item_price)
SELECT t1.item_no, t2.item_name, t3.item_price
FROM (SELECT @rank1 := @rank1 + 1 AS rank, item_no
      FROM Item_No) t1
JOIN (SELECT @rank2 := @rank2 + 1 AS rank, item_name
      FROM Item_Name) t2
ON t2.rank = t1.rank
JOIN (SELECT @rank3 := @rank3 + 1 AS rank, item_price
      FROM Item_Price) t3
ON t3.rank = t1.rank;
```

This relies on the database returning the rows in the order that they were originally inserted if you don't specify an `ORDER BY` clause. The `@rankN` variables then generate row numbers for each table, and the JOINs line up the columns from each table by this rank.